# Find the number of pairs in list

Tags: python

Suppose `lst = [7,1,5,4,2,3,6]`, `(7, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3)` are some of the pairs and in total there are 6 pairs that adds up to  `9`

(i) The order of numbers in a pair matters. For example, (7, 2) and (2, 7) are two different pairs.
(ii) A number cannot pair with itself.
(iii) There is no duplicate element in the list

```
def find_pairs(lst, key):
    count = 0
    if sum(lst[count:count+1]) == key:
        count += 1
        return count
    else:
        return find_pairs(lst[1:],key)
```

This is my code. What's wrong ?? I am getting an error
input `find_pairs([7,1,5,4,2,3,6], 9)` give `6`

```
find_pairs(list(range(1, 100, 2)), 55) #0
find_pairs(list(range(1, 100, 2)), 56) #28
```

Comment: Why 6 pairs? There are many more possible pairs between numbers in a 7-element list...

Comment: @TimPietzcker, Sum to key

Comment: @TimPietzcker It wasn't clear at all, but I think they have to add up to a given integer, in that case 9.

Comment: Yes it's suppose to add up to give 9

Answer (score 6):

There's a built-in for this in the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
def find_pairs(lst, key):
    return [(a,b) for a,b in itertools.permutations(lst, 2) if a+b==key]
```

or, more generically:

```
def find_tuples(lst, key, num=2):
    return [i for i in itertools.permutations(lst, num) if sum(i)==key]
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> find_tuples(lst, 9)
[(7, 2), (5, 4), (4, 5), (2, 7), (3, 6), (6, 3)]
>>> find_tuples(lst, 9, 3)
[(1, 5, 3), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 5), (1, 6, 2), (5, 1, 3), (5, 3, 1), (4, 2, 3), 
 (4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 6), (2, 4, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 6, 1), (3, 1, 5), (3, 5, 1), 
 (3, 4, 2), (3, 2, 4), (6, 1, 2), (6, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Although that doesn't give the count, just the list, need the added ``len`` at the end or in the function.

Comment: @aruisdante: Oh, right. In my opinion, a function called `find_pairs` should return the pairs, not their number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

1. only considering a single value at a time (`lst[i:i+1]` is a slice containing a single item, identical to `[lst[i]]`)
2. (once that is fixed) your code only considers adjacent pairs of values - in your example, `(7, 2)` would never be found because 7 is not next to 2 in the input list
3. using recursion for absolutely no good reason

Here is a more efficient version (`O(n)` instead of `O(n**2)`):

```
def find_pairs_count(lst, pair_sum):
    upto = (pair_sum - 1) // 2
    vals = set(lst)
    return 2 * sum(i <= upto and (pair_sum - i) in vals for i in lst)
```