# How to find paired sums in a list?

Tags: python, sum

I have a list x

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
```

and I want to find all pair sum equals to 10,

and it should be distinct pairs of numbers:

i.e.

```
{(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (5, 5)}.
```

here is the thoughts but I am not happy with nested loop below:

```
def test(x, n):
   pair = set()
   for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            if i !=j:
               pair.add((x[i],x[j])
```

Comment: Check this one, it's making use of `itertools`. [Find the number of pairs in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043753/find-the-number-of-pairs-in-list/23043838)

Comment: This site isn't really for code review.

Comment: I reopened this question from being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043753/find-the-number-of-pairs-in-list because the answers there are subpar and inefficient.

Comment: Also known as Two Sum problem, check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in O(n), working on a sorted list of values:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
target = 10

i = 0
j = len(values) - 1
solutions = set()

while j > i:
    if values[i] + values[j] < target:
        i += 1
    elif values[i] + values[j] > target:
        j -= 1
    else:
        solutions.add((values[i], values[j]))
        i += 1
        j -= 1

print(solutions)
# {(2, 8), (5, 5), (1, 9), (3, 7)}
```

Answer (score 2):

@ThierryLathuille's solution assumes that the list is pre-sorted. If that assumption is false, sorting the list would cost *O(n log n)*. Instead, you can use `collections.Counter` to achieve an *O(n)* time complexity while accounting for the number of available items for each value in the list:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x)
list({frozenset((10 - n, n)): (10 - n, n) for n in counts if counts[10 - n] > (n == 10 - n)}.values())
```

This returns:

```
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we know the total we want, we can repose the question - for each number, is the (total - number) in the list?

We can turn the list into a set to use a hashed lookup:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]

out = []
total = 10
for i in set(x):
    if (total - i) in set(x) and i < (total+1)/2:
        out.append((i, 10-i))
out

[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: This would fail for cases where there aren't enough numbers in the list to form a pair. For example, with `x = [5]` it should return `[]`, but this answer would return `[(5, 5)]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
y=[]
for i in x[:5]:
    q=10-i 
    w=(i,q)
    if ((q in x) & (not(w in y))):
        y.append(w)
```

this might not be an effective code to replace yours, my point of this code is just an alternative to your nested loop

Comment: Using the `in` operator for a list in a `for` loop is effectively a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension will work well here. Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
target_number = 10

solutions = [pair for pair in permutations(x, 2) if sum(pair) == 10]
print('Solutions:', solutions)
```

Output:

`Solutions: [(1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (3, 7), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 1)]`

Basically, this list comprehension looks at all the pairs that `permutations(x, 2)` returns, but only keeps the ones whose total sum equals 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get an O(n) solution using a set to store distinct values.  You need to take into account targets that are even numbers however.  Even targets will require two instances of their half value in the list but the set will not make that distinction and could find a pair of equal values when there is actually only one in the list (for example target=12 in your example values).

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
target = 10

valueSet  = set(values)
halfValue = target//2
if 2*halfValue == target and values.count(halfValue) < 2: halfValue -= 1
result   = [ (v,target-v) for v in valueSet if v <= halfValue and target-v in valueSet ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner, not the most efficient:

```py
import itertools

res = set([pair for pair in itertools.combinations(x, 2) if sum(pair)==10])

# {(2, 8), (5, 5), (9, 1), (3, 7)}
```

You are paying extra for generating the extra combinations here, as well as the overhead of the `set` constructor (not sure you can get around the latter)